# How do you convert in a select statement from varchar to binary?

Tags: database

Please break up the select statement and do not give me bits of code such as, "select convert..."Also do not beat me up about this when I am a DBA not a Developer so points taken off wouldn't be what you call, "ethical".

convert col1 from binary to varchar

select
col1,
col2
from tab1 
where col1 = ' '

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer because people obviously do not want to share knowledge.

```
select 
col1, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), col2) As Col2Covertedasexample
from tab1
```